# nginx location block failing due to rewrite

Tags: regex, wordpress, nginx, configuration

I'm trying to get the following code to work:

```
location = /test-site/wp-login.php {
           allow  192.168.0.56;
           include         /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
           fastcgi_pass php;
                           fastcgi_index  index.php;
           fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  /var/www/test-site.com/html$fastcgi_script_name;
            deny all;
    }
```

The problem is, due to the multisite configuration on Wordpress, there are 3 rewrites that need to be performed in order to get to the right subsite. Even with the rewrites, the above block doesn't work because with the rewrite, it's stripping out the /test-site/ part.

Instead, it matches this and uses this nginx configuration:

```
    location = /wp-login.php {
            #allow  192.168.0.0/16;
            allow  192.168.0.56;
            include         /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
            fastcgi_pass php;
                            fastcgi_index  index.php;
            fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  /var/www/test-site.com/html$fastcgi_script_name;

            deny all;
    }
```

I've had some success changing the rewrite to ignore /test-site/ and keep it, but then it changes the $fastcgi_script_name variable to be /var/www/site.com/html/test-site/wp-login and the /test-site/ directory doesn't exist because it's actually a subsite.

If I take out the $fastcgi_script_name variable and hardcode /var/www/site.com/html/wp-login.php to be there instead, it gets me to the site, but it doesn't set the variable back to the proper value to find and of the image or style files.

Anyone have any experience with this? I'm basically trying to allow everyone access to wp-login.php on one subsite, but block them from any of the other subsites in my wordpress environment.

Comment: From the Nginx docs: "Also, using the “=” modifier it is possible to define an exact match of URI and location. If an exact match is found, the search terminates. For example, if a “/” request happens frequently, defining “location = /” will speed up the processing of these requests, `as search terminates right after the first comparison`." I've highlighted what I believe may be your issue. Try removing the `=` sign and just do `location /test-site/wp-login.php`.

Comment: I thought so too, but the rewrite that's in the config file changes the URI to just /wp-login.php. I've tried removing the rewrite, but that breaks that individual subsite. Thanks for the thought though.